# Ideals in Gaussian integers

Tags: ring-theory, prime-numbers, ideals

> Let $R:=\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Prove that every nonzero prime ideal
>   $\mathfrak{P}$ of $R$ belongs to one of the following families:
>
> 1. $\mathfrak{P}=(1+i)R$
> 2. $\mathfrak{P}=(a+bi)R$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a^2+b^2$ is an odd prime $p$ which is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$
> 3. $\mathfrak{P}=pR$ where $p$ is an odd prime which is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.
>
> **Hint**: in case 3), let $\alpha\in R$ be written as $c+id$ with $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and suppose $\alpha\notin\mathfrak{P}$. Consider
>   $\alpha\overline{\alpha}=c^2+d^2$; prove that $p$ does not divide
>   $c^2+d^2$, so that there exists an integer $e$ such that
>   $(c^2+d^2)e=1\bmod p$. Conclude that
>   $\alpha\cdot\overline{\alpha}e=1\bmod\mathfrak{P}$.

I can't understand the hints that i'm given. I've proved that $p$ doesn't divide $c^2+d^2$, in fact $p=3\bmod 4$ implies that $p$ is also a Gaussian prime, so if it divides $c^2+d^2=(c+di)(c-di)$ then it should divide one of the two factors, which is impossible.

Hence, being $p$ a rational prime, not dividing $c^2+d^2$, it must be coprime to $c^2+d^2$ so that there exists $e$ such that etc. etc.

And now? I have proven that $\alpha$ is invertible modulo $\mathfrak{P}$. How can i use this?

Comment: This shows that $R/pR$ is a field, so $pR$ is a maximal (hence prime) ideal.

Comment: Have you proven this theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a prime ideal $P \subset R$ is that for any $x,y \in R$ such that $xy \in P$ either $x \in P$ or $y \in P$ (or both).

In your case, let $x,y \in R$ be such that $xy \in P$. Assume for a contradiction that neither $x\in  P$ nor $y \in P $. Then both $x$ and $y$ are invertible mod $P$(as you've already proved) and therefore so is their product! So their product cannot possible lie in $P$(it would imply $1 \in P$) unless $P=R$ which is clearly impossible.